# Inserting data into MySQL using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have tried to insert name and password to a table in mysql using this code. It generates the alert of success but the data doesn't get added to the table. 
Can somebody please resolve this?

My html file -

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">Test Form</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            
            <form onsubmit="return false" id="frm">
    
              <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="50">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="password" name="password" size="50">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">
                  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" value="Send">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </form>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    
  </body>
  

</html>
```

And the javascript - I want to do the insertions without loading any other pages (staying on the same html page). This ajax part pops up the alert but the data is not added to the table.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#frm").submit(function() {
                    var name= $("#name").val();
                    var password= $("#password").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "db.php",
                        data: "name=" + name+ "&password=" + password,
                        success: function(data) {
                           alert("success!");
                        }
                    });


                });
      </script>
```

Finally the PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dynamic";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$order = "INSERT INTO userdata (name, password) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[password]')";


$result = $conn->query($order);  
if($result){
    echo("Successfully added!");
} else{
   echo("Input failed!");
}
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements.  That should solve your problem. Also do not under any circumstance store passwords in plain text

Comment: You php code will result in `success` for both the error case and the failure case, because both will return a  `200` status code, in the failure case you should not only echo the error, but also change the status code. Beside that you *must never*  pass data from an untrusted source this way to you query.  If  `name` or `password` contains a  `'` your query will in the best case only fail, in the worst case it can be use to do some sql injection.

Comment: $order = "INSERT INTO userdata (name, password) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".md5($_POST['password'])."')";.
change your query  with this one..

Comment: Before execute your query print your query first. You can use `print_r($order)` or `echo $order`. I believe that your query is not build properly.

Comment: Thanks, I am using name and password just for and example. Can you tell me a way to check if the insert query is actually run or not?

Comment: Print the query and check your ajax response using console.

Comment: @Priyank it is true that the password should be hashed. But on the one hand md5 shouldn't be used for this task for a while now and a slated method with a not broken algorithm should be used instead, this most likely wouldn't solve the problem, because if the data would not be inserted without a hash why should it be accepted with a hashed password (assuming the input does not contain any ' which is a general problem with the query that you do not solve either).

Comment: Thanks to all.. Data get added now, but the success message shows even when I misspell the database name. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$frm to #btnSubmit

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
         var data = {name: $("#name").val(), password: $("#password").val()'}
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "db.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert("success!");
                    }
                });


            });
  </script>
```

Comment: This is not the actual solution.

Comment: You code has syntax errors. Beside that why should the OP change the submit event listener to listen on the button? The form element is the correct element to listen to the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in HTML :

```
<form onsubmit="return false" id="frm" method="POST">

</form>
```

add form method POST

Change in your PHP code:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (name, password)
VALUES ($name, $password)";
```

and close your connection

```
$conn->close();
```